# Converted timezone does not display properly in ArcMap

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, sql-view, timestamp, arcgis-10.7

*(Oracle 12c geodatabase)*

I have a view that converts a UTC timestamp to Eastern Time using the `from_tz` function:

```sql
create or replace view test_vw as (
select
    cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as rownum_,
    from_tz(
         cast(to_date('2019/11/02 05:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp)      
    , 'UTC') at time zone 'US/Eastern' as my_timestamp
from
    dual
);

   ROWNUM_ MY_TIMESTAMP                       
---------- -----------------------------------
         1 11/02/2019 1:00:00.000000 AM -04:00
```

In Toad, the SQL converts 5:00 am UTC to 1:00 am Eastern Time.

That is the expected result.

---

However, when I use the view in ArcMap 10.7.1, the timestamp does not display the correct time:

[image]

It displays 5:00 am UTC, instead of 1:00 am Eastern Time.

Is there a way to display the converted time correctly in ArcMap?

Answer (score 0):

I can convert the offset timestamp to a character, then back to a timestamp.

It's pretty ugly. But from a cursory look, it seems to work.

---

A simple, non-timezone related example:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

The actual solution:

```sql
create or replace view test_vw as (
select
    cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as rownum_,
    to_timestamp(to_char(
        from_tz(
            cast(to_date('2019/11/02 05:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp)      
        , 'UTC') at time zone 'US/Eastern' 
    , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as my_timestamp
from
    dual
);
```